# spark plug and generator storage

Tags: long-term-storage, generator

I have a question regarding the DS4000S generator. Reading the manual on the how to storage paragraph, it says to drain the fuel and disconnect the spark plug. I am not sure if I should just loosen it, or completely remove it, leaving the hole open? Does the piston chamber seals itself when removing the plug? Should I cover the hole somehow? I am looking forward to your suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, do not loosen or remove the spark plug. "Disconnect" when in reference to a spark plug means to pull the cap at the end of the spark plug wire until the cap pops off the spark plug's metal terminal. Don't pull the wire, pull the cap. When you re-connect it, you should feel a little internal snap as it makes full mechanical contact.

So if you want to follow their instructions, disconnect the spark plug.

Frankly, this is a stupid and pointless instruction, and is simply an example of ***Lawyers Gone Wild***. This is a pull-start generator with no electric starter, and there is no way for it to start by itself. (Preventing automatic starting is a valid safety-related reason to disconnect a spark plug.)

And guess what? The generator came to you from warehouse storage with the spark plug attached. So everybody should disconnect the spark plug for storage except the manufacturer? Double stupid.

And furthermore: There is nothing in the starting instructions to inform you that you should re-connect the spark plug if you want to use the generator. Triple stupid.

And holy cow, in the troubleshooting section under "Generator won't start" there is nothing that says "Re-connect the spark plug that we told you to disconnect." Quadruple stupid.

Have I made my point? Do as you wish. It doesn't hurt anything to disconnect the spark plug, but there's no real reason to do so.

If you have already loosened or removed the spark plug, be sure to tighten it again before you put the generator in storage.

Comment: Thank you for not only explaining how to disconnect it, but also the logic (or lack of thereof) behind it. Funny thing is, I saw a youtube video by the manufacturer on how to prepare the generator for long term storage, and there was not mention on disconnecting the spark plug. Oh well.

Comment: @Max_IT Right, I guess the manufacturer didn't want to win the Stupid Video of the Month Award!! Good luck with your generator.